# How can I put string inside array without repeat

Tags: java

I have this text below

```
String text = "a b c a a b b b c d a z e q e m a m d z e"
```

How I can put them in array like this

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
//array above should be has {"a","b","c","d","z","e","q","m"}
```

How I can do it ?

Comment: Use **Set** instead of ArrayList,bcause Set collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Comment: @Kabir Please explain him what is use of set instead of ArrayList

Comment: Check set example :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a set with your list clear your list add set items to you list

```
yourList.addAll(Arrays.asList(text.split(" "))); 
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(yourList);
yourList.clear();
yourList.addAll(set);
```

Comment: Where is text variable ?

Comment: this will not preserve the order of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Split your `String` by space, create a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) out of it - this will remove duplicates and preserve element order (since [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) does not allow duplicate values and it uses [`Object::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods for it. `LinkedHashSet` also preserves element adding order). And then create `ArrayList` using it's copy constructor :

```
LinkedHashSet<String> set = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s"))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

one more approach using streams:

```
String text = "a b c a a b b b c d a z e q e m a m d z e";
ArrayList<String> array = Pattern.compile(" ")
                                 .splitAsStream(text)
                                 .distinct()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
System.out.println(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

> String text = "a b c a a b b b c d a z e q e m a m d z e"
>
> ArrayList array = new ArrayList<>();
>
> array.addAll(Arrays.asList(text.split(" ")));

Answer (score 0):

use set to  it don't repeat element

```
String text = "a b c a a b b b c d a z e q e m a m d z e"

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
or change DTRING TO CHAR
        set .addAll(text);
```